# countdown in django using keith wood countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am using keith wood countdown, How do i set the default countdown to (14 days) and it will start when after the user login to their profile, and the countdown will still continue even if the user logout or leave the page?

```
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
<script>
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do these steps. When user logs in get the `austDay` and save this to your local storage(Not recommended as user may login to different browser) or the database.
and if user is going on the countdown page then get the data from the DB and pass the function `austDay`. So this will help you to determine and send notification to user once he finishes the day.

Comment: @Kaushik how do i pass the function to austDay if i use database?

Comment: you keep the date in db. and then pull the data and keep in hidden variable and then on document ready read the variable and init the countdown

Comment: the timer still continue even the user leave the page ? or he logout

Comment: Yes as you've saved the date to db. So the next time you comes to the page the austDay will be same and the timer will be reduced.